# Laravel + PhpStorm + кеширование. При работе через IDE изменения не видны на сайте

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, кэширование

Столкнулся с очень странной для меня ситуацией.
Если работаю через PhpStorm (выгружаю туда продакшн проект + синхронизирую), то при попытке внести какие-либо изменения в blade (др. не тестил), после save+upload на сервер не вижу изменений на самом сайте, хотя по факту на сервере они происходят и файл перезаписывается.

В тоже самое время, открываю обычное FTP соединение через Filezilla + обычный редактор, вижу изменения сделанные через PhpStorm.

Если же я сохраняю через Filezilla или напрямую в RemoteHost PhpStorm, то изменения **отображаются** на сайте.

Команда `artisan view:clear` вполне решает проблему, но не буду же я постоянно ее вбивать через консоль, после каждого save+upload. Сделал также Exclude Paths для папок tests, storage/framework, .cache.

Подскажите пожалуйста, я наверное что-то упускаю.

Comment: Сайт кешируется, можно поставить расширение, что бы удалять кеш по нажатию

Answer (score 0):

в миксинах пропиши автообновление https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/browsersync
У тебя кэшируется кеш еще вариант php artisan view:clear 
Самый последний вариант ctrl+f5
Если работаешь с js поменяй в asset js можешь прописать  пример

```
<script src="script.js?<?=yourversion?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```